# multiple string replace using variable

Tags: javascript

I have to replace multiple words in a string.

my code is like this

```
var csku = "{len}";
 var value = 5;
 var finalPrice = "({con}*{len})+{wid}+{fixed_var}+{extra}+{sqft}+{len}";
console.log(finalPrice.replace(csku, value));
```

Using this code I got this solution

```
({con}*5)+{wid}+{fixed_var}+{extra}+{sqft}+{len}
```

but I want this

```
({con}*5)+{wid}+{fixed_var}+{extra}+{sqft}+5
```

I google it for replacing multiple words in the string using one call I find this

```
str.replace(/X|x/g, '');
```

Here `/` and `g` is used for multiple replace and in this format I have to add static word but in my code `csku` is not fixed so how can I replace all words in one call using variable

Comment: There is no jQuery in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code from the duplicate to create a [Regex object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) using the variable

```js
var csku = "{len}";
var value = 5;
var finalPrice = "({con}*{len})+{wid}+{fixed_var}+{extra}+{sqft}+{len}";
var re = new RegExp(csku, "g");
console.log(finalPrice.replace(re, value));
```

Answer (score 1):

use `new RegExp(cksu, 'g')` to create a regular expression that'll match all `cksu`.

`new RegExp('{len}', 'g')` will return `/{len}/g` meaning all global matches.

so `finalPrice.replace(new RegExp(cksu, 'g'), value)` will replace all global matches of `cksu` with `value`.

```js
var csku = "{len}";
var value = 5;
var finalPrice = "({con}*{len})+{wid}+{fixed_var}+{extra}+{sqft}+{len}";

console.log(finalPrice.replace(new RegExp(csku, 'g'), value));
```

Answer (score -2):

Standart replace function change just first match. You can use this function:

```
function ReplaceAll(Source, stringToFind, stringToReplace) {
            var temp = Source;
            var index = temp.indexOf(stringToFind);
            while (index != -1) {
                temp = temp.replace(stringToFind, stringToReplace);
                index = temp.indexOf(stringToFind);
            }
            return temp;
        }
```